# SQL multiple left join + join with a select

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL. I need help with left join with an select.

The part I'm interested in:

```
Select...
from table t1
left join table t2
on t1.id=t2.id,
left join (select * from table 3 where ...) t3
on t1.id=t3.id
where t1.id='something'
```

Also i tried to moved in the where clause the t1.id(+)=t3.id but didn't work.

Comment: remove the `,` between the joins.

Comment: Thx, I'm a noob :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
Select...
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left join
     t3
      on t1.id = t3.id and
         <t3 conditions go here>
where t1.id = 'something'
```

You have a superfluous comma -- and commas should never be in the `FROM` clause.

You also have a superfluous subquery.  You can get the same functionality by just including the condition in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Thanks! But I m using the select because in that table I have all values in a row and I have to place them in 3 different colums.

Comment: If i got this select to join with how do i proced?

Comment: left join (select a.th, min(a.date)
               from table a
              where a.th like '&a'
                and a.desc is not null
              group by a.th) t2
              on t1.th = t11.th